# Are there shooting modifiers for Large targets?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, creature-size, shooting

A player made a Troll, Giant subtype, so he is **3.5 meters** (11 feet, 3 inches) in height and I am wondering: are rules where it says he is any **easier** to hit **than**, say, a 1.2m dwarf?

If not it seems a bit unfair to me toward smaller targets. Yet, I just started to GM Shadowrun, so I could be overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're interested in 5th edition:

*Run & Gun* contains an optional rule (RG2, p. 108), but it's based on \$CON + STR\$, so dwarfs are usually easier to hit than humans. The following modifiers apply to the attack roll based on the sum:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|}\hline
CON+STR&modifier\\\hline
2\text{ to }4& -1\\\hline
5\text{ to }10& 0\\\hline
11\text{ to }15& +1\\\hline
\geq16& +2\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

There are smaller (-2 and -3) and larger (+3) modifiers, but those don't apply to metahuman sized targets.

As for fairness:

Trolls have a maximum INT that is reduced by 1. Also the cost of building a troll is extraordiarily high. Giants als have a reduced REA max.

But why is using the same modifier unfair? You knew the benefits and drawbacks of building a dwarf/troll when creating the char and size doesn't seem to be considered a advantage or drawback when determining the costs of a metatype (except for higher lifestyle cost).

Comment: The giant is an awakened so Con and Str are not his stats. He's a flabby giant. 
Penalties for having such a creature aside, I thought would be unfair since he can literally become antitank cover for the rest of his team when he dies and falls down. He is enormous, hence wondering were there any modifiers. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @StoryKillinger uhm... Giant is a troll metatype, they are generally around the 3.5 meters mark with a 11+ on Con+Str. to frame it simple: **Giants are Metahumans, not creatures**